# Use network adapter in Kali Linux using vmbox?

Tags: networking, wifi, kali-linux, network-interface

I would like to use my network adapter from my laptop in kali linux. I tried changing the network settings inside vmbox but I can't get it to work. I am using oracle virtual machine.

Kali linux is connected through a wired connection.
[image]

The vmbox network settings.
[image]

On my windows machine I am connected through: Intel Dual Band Wireless-AC 7265

Comment: NAT is not an option and you want to bridge your wireless interface?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And that's impossible. A short google would have told you that the NIC isn't passed through, and that the only virtual interface your Kali VM is ever going to see is wired.

Comment: That's a bummer, but it should work if I boot up kali using dual boot right?

Comment: Most likely, depending on how recent / well supported your laptops Wifi adapter is. Might pay to Google for "Linux" your adapter model " before you install...

Comment: Alright thanks for your answer, I checked and it seems to be supported.

Comment: @Gewoo You don't have to dual boot. You can run kali from a live USB and have hardware access. Another option is to buy a [wifi USB adapter](https://superuser.com/a/1231899).